# hadoop + can we install zookeeper servers on kafka hosts

Tags: hadoop, kafka, zookeeper

we want to dedicated the zookeeper servers only for kafka machines
so each kafka machine include the zookeeper server
and zookeeper server will serve only the kafka host and not other application

in that case is it ok?

Comment: Please clarify, are you talking to host zookeeper on kafka hosts itself? if yes, that is bad idea, If you want to keep zookeeper separate from kafka that is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka recommends in fact dedicated zookeper servers. I didn't get your question right - do you want to put zookeeper on the kafka broker machines? This is not a good idea unless we talk about development.

In production, both server classes should have their own dedicated machines since the overall system relies on each component having the max capacity for its own purposes, e.g. zookeeper shouldn't be allowed to swap at all.

Another reason is maintainability and availability - Brokers and zookeepers each are designed to recover from outages of a single cluster. I wouldn't want to deal with a cluster situation where I have to deal with a dual outage of zookeeper and broker.